# console.log in devtools - new user puzzled

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

While taking my codeschool [exercise](http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/chapters/3/challenges/6) on devtools console, I'm happily using console.log to print out the stuff they tell me to. Then I'm using console.assert to check some statements. Then I'm supposed to use console.log again (?) to print out a final string.

Instead of the string, I'm getting **undefined**. Like the log method is broken. Apparently there's a lesson here, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm ... this works for me:

```
> console.log("A");
A
undefined
> console.assert(1 == 1);
undefined
> console.assert(1 == 2);
Assertion failed:
undefined
> console.log("B");
B
undefined
```

Comment: Can you post the exact lines which you put in the console.